# How can we iterate on slave list in a jenkins job?

Tags: jenkins

Is it possible to iterate on slaves with a particular label in a jenkins job?
For example, lets say I have few slave with label "redhat". I have a job in which I want to logically do something like:

for slave in slave_list_with_label_redhat do
  ssh someuser@${slave.hostname} 
done

Thanks in advance!!

Edit use case in detail: 
So this is to workaround a bug in jenkins where archiving artifacts fails from AIX slave. https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-13614

So what we really want to do is once the build is complete on build slave, we would like to scp "build files" to available jenkins aix slaves and install and run few tests on test slaves.

Comment: I am not aware of a way to get the list of slaves within a job. You might be able to do something with a groovy script. But don't ask me for details. --- Why do you want to connect to these slaves? What is your Business Case? May be someone can suggest you a completely different option to achieve your goal.

Comment: Hi Peter thanks for your response, I have updated description above with use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually let my jobs download all necessary artifacts. So your option would be to add another build step to your build job and archive the artifacts manually outside of Jenkins. You can use SCM tools (not perfect for binary artifacts but offer great auditing features) or binary artifact repositories (e.g. nexus - best, but I have no Idea about the auditing features) or just a remote filesystem (you can mount it locally on your slave machines). The build job just needs to pass some information to the test jobs so that these can get the right artifact. This way, Jenkins still decides where the test job(s) will run but the slaves have always access to the artifacts.

Comment: that helped!!, posting solutions below.

Answer (score 1):

You might find https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Elastic+Axis to fit your needs

I think this is used as part of the multi-configuration (Axis) create job and you can then select this as one of the axes

[image]